# Cannot open other member's project in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

I don't understand how it works. I'm new to Team Foundation Server and currently I have a small team. The co-worker can open my project file and run just fine (by double clicking the solution file right in the source control explorer window).

I can open my project file the same way but cannot open his project file. Clicking the solution file does load the solution but the files in there cannot be opened. It says something like this:

> Cannot find the file "d:\....". It may have been moved or deleted.

The path "d:...." is actually the path on his machine. While in my machine it's mapped to a different path. But I don't understand why it cannot recognize it.

At first I thought the mapped path structure should be the same across all members' machines but if so my co-worker could have not opened my project file.

The status of the solution is Yes for ***Latest***, meaning the files are loaded and copied to my local folder normally. Not sure if it matters but I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and my co-worker uses Visual Studio 2013.

I've tried searching around but could not find anything with the error message.

### Edit

To clarify it more, if I browse the file directly inside the source control explorer window, the file can be opened (but if it such as is some designer-supported file like ***.xaml*** - the designer then is not shown up). What I'm having trouble with is opening the file loaded in the solution (inside the Solution Explorer window). As I said clicking the solution file in Source Control Explorer window does load the solution, but because there is something wrong with the files path, I cannot open them as well as build and run the solution.

Right-clicking on the file in the loaded solution, select Properties, I can see that the Full Path is actually the path on his machine, so weird.

Comment: you need to create a local workspace to map the solution root folder, then all files in that solution are mapped to your local folder.(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx) After you created the workspace, also do the get latest version operation. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181387.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your workspace is all messed up. Are you trying to share a workspace?

If so you should not. Each developer should have their own workspace local to their computer that is unique to them.

Try creating a new workspace and using that...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by workspace but each one of us has different machine with different local folders. I understand that what I need here is mapping and I can see it seems to be OK (initially the ***Not mapped*** link-like button is shown when you select some item in the left treeview which represents the server's folders, I clicked on that and mapped all folders OK).

Comment: For information of workspace, you can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181383.aspx